# How to Debug Electron.NET application

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, electron.net

I'm Developing  an application using **Electron.NET** and **.Net Core 2.1** in Visual Studio Code, Now I'm Facing an issue in **Debugging** an **Electron.NET** Application.I have also Configure **lunch.json** file for debugging it,but still not able to debug the app.

Help me for Opt-out from this situation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your application with the Electron.NET CLI: "dotnet electronize start", and attach to the running exe process.

Answer (score 1):

### PreRequisite:

1. This is the assumption that your electron application is referring the dlls or projects and its symbols.

### Steps:

1. Step1: start the electron application
2. Step2: In visual studion IDE goto Debug and select 'Attach to process'
3. Step3: In the window, select the process of the application and click attach
4. Step4: Put the breakpoints in the Visual Studio IDE
5. Step5: Now you will be able to debug the c# code from electron app.